# How to do an initial snapshot load with debezium mysql connector kafka?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using Kafka Cluster and Debezium MySql connector to get messages from database updates to an Elasticsearch. For a while I was doing some test and I ended up with a mixed ES so I wanted to do a fresh full load to Elasticsearch.

So I wanted to stop the debezium connector to stop feeding ES and remove all the indexes so when I start again the connector it could do a full load. As far as I know, the connector only works with `pause/resume` actions and those does not do an initial load.

At this moment I will remove manually the connector and the topics created and re-create them so it can load as it was initial but any ideas of how to perform this clean up process in the right steps?

Comment: Debezium does do a bulk load on a fresh connector creation. So delete the old one. Don't pause it

Comment: Thanks for your answer cricket, but since the offset in kafka topics were already in place, it will not load the data again if I only delete and recreate the connector.

Comment: You might be able to use `kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a better way but this solution worked for me:

1. Stopped the services for the `/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties` daemon.

```
sudo systemctl stop confluent-connect-distributed.service
```

2. Delete the connector of Debezium

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8083/connectors/<connector name>
```

3. delete all the topics related to my work, in this case this kafka cluster was a dev one so I deleted all the topics, even the defaults ones.

```
__consumer_offsets
_confluent-command
_schemas
connect-configs
connect-offsets
connect-status
```

```
kafka-topics --bootstrap-server <kafka bootstrap> --delete --topic <topic name>
```

4. Create again the default topics

```
kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server <boostrap kafka> --topic connect-configs --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact
kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server <boostrap kafka> --topic connect-offsets --replication-factor 3 --partitions 50 --config cleanup.policy=compact
kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server <boostrap kafka> --topic connect-status --replication-factor 3 --partitions 10 --config cleanup.policy=compact
```

5. Start service again

```
sudo systemctl start confluent-connect-distributed.service
```

6. Create connector again

```
curl -s -i -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
    http://localhost:8083/connectors/<connector name>/config \
    -d '<json>'
```

This way you will end up with a initial snapshot in elasticsearch.

Comment: Did you find a better way of doing it? I have almost the same process for this

Comment: No really, I have automated this process with a bash script and do the initial snapshot. So now I just ran one script with all of these things and the script is separated by environment.